Rviz2 can not load resource of mesh geometry
I have a working urdf for my robot that I could visualize in rviz2 and publish over /robot_description well. However, I have recently started trying to simulate my robot over in Gazebo and I found that Gazebo was not generating the geometry for my sensors. Apparently it was because I was using the old <mesh filename="package://my_package/meshes/rp_lidar.dae"/>, and I have changed that to <mesh filename="$(find my_package)/meshes/rp_lidar.dae"/>
Now Gazebo loads the geometry without problems, but rviz2 throws the following error:
[rviz2-2] [ERROR] [1717399115.519178958] [rviz2]: Could not load resource [/home/alejandro/code/workspace/install/my_package/share/my_package/meshes/rp_lidar.dae]: Unable to open file "/home/alejandro/code/workspace/install/my_package/share/my_package/meshes/rp_lidar.dae".

The file is there and exists, as you can imagine, because gazebo displays it, but rviz2 is unable.

I'm encountering a same issue.
Before,<mesh filename="package://my_package/meshes/rp_lidar.dae"/> but it can't be loaded in Gazebo that's why I changed it into <mesh filename="$(find my_package)/meshes/rp_lidar.dae"/> and it works now on gazebo. But new problem arises as the rviz2 Could not load the resource...: Unable to open file. Any updates? ROS2 Humble Gazebo Fortress

I had this same issue a few weeks ago. The fix for me was to use "file://" inside of my URDF.
Give this a try:
<mesh filename="file://$(find my_package)/meshes/rp_lidar.dae"/>


That did the trick, thanks!
